# Not able to send messages to Azure Service Bus from Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I’ve been having an issue with a long running Azure Function App. It’s basically reads in a pipe delimeted file, creates an Employee object from the values, get the corresponding employee database record, and do a database insert or update.

Since it’s taking so long and spiking the CPU, some suggested that I read in each line of the file and send it to a Service Bus. Then have another function inside of my Function App to read from the queue and do my record comparison.

I’ve never used Service Bus before but went through and set one up in Azure. Now I’m trying to use the ServiceBus output binding in my Function App to send the message but I’m not getting it to work. I’ve been following along with some different articles I found including the following ones from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp

I have the ServiceBusConnection added to my local.settings.json file. I pulled the connection string from the Azure Service Bus "Shared Access policies" section. I double checked the settings and made sure that the property name is correct. However, since the connection string is in the return section I don't know how to debug and confirm it's actually pulling the connection string and that it is correct.

This is what I’ve come up with so far but I’m not seeing any messages in my queue.

```
    [FunctionName("ProcessEmployeeInput")]
    [return: ServiceBus("myQueueName", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
    public string Run(
       [BlobTrigger("%InputContainer%/%InputFolder%/{name}.txt", Connection = "StorageConnection")] Stream fileBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Azure Function START.");
        log.LogInformation($"Processing file {name}.");
    
        string jsonEmployee = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (var srFile = new StreamReader(fileBlob))
            {
                srFile.ReadLine();   //first line is a header. Just call ReadLine to skip past it. 
    
                while (!srFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var record = srFile.ReadLine();

                    //Create an Employee object and map the properties.                 

Employee employee = MapEmployeeProperties(record, log);
    
                    //Serialize into text before sending to service bus                         

jsonEmployee = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError("Error processing file. {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
        }
    
        return jsonEmployee;
    }
```

**Error Message**

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I didn't see this at first but from this message it sounds like it can't find the Service Bus endpoint. Since the connection is in the output binding, I can confirm it can find it and that it is correct.

Comment: do you have any error message ?

Comment: @Thomas I updated my original post.

Comment: Is this running locally or in Azure?   Are there any restrictions applied to the Service Bus endpoint, such as running in a VNET?   Generally, that category of error is due to network issues connecting via the AMQP ports (5671, 5672) and using the `AmqpWebSockets` transport type often helps.   That is specified as part of the `host.json` settings, described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings

Comment: @JesseSquire I'm running the Function App locally for development but I'm connecting to a service bus in Azure. I have a feeling it's Network related but I would have thought that since I can connect to a Blob Storage in the same Resource Group that I would be okay network wise. Maybe it has to do with the ports. I'll take a look at the link you sent.

Comment: @JesseSquire Adding the info to the hosts file worked! I had found that article on Friday but hadn't actually added it until you sent the link again. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped get you unblocked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that @*Caverman* for solved the issue. Thank you @*Jesse Squire* for your suggestions that helped to fix the issue. Posting this on behalf of your discussion so that it will be beneficial for other community members.

**Workaround:-**

> ****To resolve the above issue  make sure that we have following in our `host.json` file and the nuget package
> `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` is installed in the environment***.*
>
> `host.json` file example:-
>
> ```
> {
>     "version": "2.0",
>     "extensions": {
>         "serviceBus": {
>             "clientRetryOptions":{
>                 "mode": "exponential",
>                 "tryTimeout": "00:01:00",
>                 "delay": "00:00:00.80",
>                 "maxDelay": "00:01:00",
>                 "maxRetries": 3
>             },
>             "prefetchCount": 0,
>             "transportType": "amqpWebSockets",
>             "webProxy": "https://proxyserver:8080",
>             "autoCompleteMessages": true,
>             "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "00:05:00",
>             "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
>             "maxConcurrentSessions": 8,
>             "maxMessageBatchSize": 1000,
>             "sessionIdleTimeout": "00:01:00",
>             "enableCrossEntityTransactions": false
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION FAQ***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq#what-ports-do-i-need-to-open-on-the-firewall--) .